# When did oracle start supporting "top": select top ? p2_.PRODUCT_ID from PRODUCT?

Tags: oracle

When did oracle start supporting "top":

```
select top ? p2_.PRODUCT_ID from PRODUCT?
```

Comment: Why do you think Oracle started supporting "top"?

Comment: Beats me.  It was a while ago.  Judging from the syntax is was generated by Hibernate.  I may have had the dialect wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am not sure ORACLE ever had a TOP function.  You want to use a TOP-N query.

For example:

```
select  *
  from  (SELECT  *
           FROM  foo
          where  foo_id=[number]
       order by  foo_id desc)
 where  rownum <= 3
```

This will get you the top three results (because I order by desc in the sub query)

Comment: The keyword 'rownum' is the physical row number in the database, which is why you have to sort it first, then apply the criteria.

Answer (score 4):

Oracle does not support the TOP keyword.  The query

```
SELECT TOP 10 product_id
  FROM product
```

will generate a syntax error because the TOP 10 clause is not recognized, at least through Oracle 11.1 (the current production release).

Answer (score 1):

[`TOP`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176104.aspx) is supported by SQL server not by Oracle. Don't confuse with [FIRST_ROWS](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements006.htm#BABGCCFG) hit that is for retrieve the best plan for the firs rows not to stop after a number of results.

As other said, the Oracle solution is to play with [ROWNUM](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/pseudocolumns009.htm#SQLRF00255) pseudocolumn.